# Manu Smriti and its laws on the social system: Can a Brahmin can compel a Sudra to be servile?

Tags: manu-smriti, varnashrama

Is it true as stated in Manu Smriti that a Brahmin can compel a Sudra to be servile or it is an interpolation?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! can u pls specify which verse of Manu Smriti you are referring?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A Brahman may compel a Shudra, whether bought or unbought, to do servile work for he is created by the creator to be the slave of a Brahmana. (Manu VIII

Comment: viprasevaiva śūdrasya viśiṣṭaṃ karma kīrtyate | yadato'nyad hi kurute tad bhavatyasya niṣphalam || 123 || The service of the Brāhmaṇa is described as the distinctive duty of the Śūdra; everything else that he does is fruitless for him.—(123)

Comment: can it be said that the above was not stated like that and is a interpolation or it is meant like that

Comment: If we use our modern day sensibilities and thinking to judge ancient scriptures like Manu Smriti then all the verses will appear as "interpolated" to us. @itha

Comment: okay...so in moderndays...these can be out...but how can core thoughts change in time ..so i think the obligation still continues but not implemented

Comment: Why does anyone read that book, I don't get it. Perhaps because it has been made famous by Anti-Hindus and our people are making it more and more popular by reading and asking questions about it. Why don't you read Veda or Upanishads?

Comment: The interpretation will depend on whether by Brahmin and Sudra caste is meant or Varna is meant. If Varna is meant then the Manu Smriti verse is an appeal to a person of Sudra Varna to perform Karma Yoga.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay I don't see the verse for compel and from what I have seen a Shudra is suggested to work for a Brahmina for his benefit as helping a holy man is a holy act. I don't see force anywhere.

Comment: A Shudras work is indeed service, but I see it more like today's workers serving a big corporation over slavery per se.

Answer (score 2):

**brahmana cannot compel a shudra**, as per manu dharmashastra 2.24 :

> *etāndvijātayo deśān saṃśrayeran prayatnataḥ | śūdrastu yasmin kasmin vā nivased vṛttikarśitaḥ || 24 ||*
>
> *The twice-born people should seek to resort to these countries; **the Śūdra may however, when distressed for a living, reside in any
> land.**—(24).*

Answer (score 0):

"BG 4.1: The Supreme Lord Shree Krishna said: I taught this eternal science of Yog to the Sun God, Vivasvan, who passed it on to Manu; and Manu, in turn, instructed it to Ikshvaku"

"O subduer of enemies, the saintly kings thus received this science of Yog in a continuous tradition. But with the long passage of time, it was lost to the world." BG Ch4 verse 2

### Lack of continuity of the og wisdom.So i don't think that we have og version of manusmriti now it got interpolated over time.